# inside vue brackets javascript function not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want value of checkboxes to be written in h1 element after checked I tried `testCheck.join(',')` but i get errors basically it's not working any solutions?

```js
  template:`
    <div>
      <form>
        <input v-model="this.testCheck" type="checkbox" value="Shooter">This is a shooter game
        <br>
        <input v-model="this.testCheck" type="checkbox" value="RPG">this is a RPG game
        <br>
        <input v-model="this.test">
        <br>
        <h1>{{ testCheck.join(', ')}}</h1>
      </form>
  </div>
  `
  data:{
    testCheck:'',
    test:''
```

Comment: What's the full example code? What's the error? "Basically it's not working" isn't detailed enough. Based on what you have so far, `testCheck` is a string, so it won't have `join()` anyway (an array would). https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<input v-model="this.testCheck"` should be `<input v-model="testCheck"` (Remove `this`) - basic examples her: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html

Next `join` is an **array** method - you should declare the data as an array.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

```
const element = "hello";
/* not working */
console.log(element.join()) /* Uncaught TypeError: element.join is not a function */
```

VS correct code:

```
/* working */
const element = ["hello", "world"];
console.log(element.join()) /* "hello world" */
```

**Working snippet:**

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    testCheck: [],
    test:'Hello',
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <form>
    <input v-model="testCheck" type="checkbox" value="Shooter">This is a shooter game
    <br>
    <input v-model="testCheck" type="checkbox" value="RPG">this is a RPG game
    <br>
    <input v-model="test">
    <br>
    <h1>{{ testCheck.join(', ')}}</h1>
  </form>
</div>
```